# Function arguments alignment in C

Tags: c, function, pointers, arguments, size

The array in procedure breaking procedure arguments alignment.
Having a following code:

```
void _func(unsigned long cnt, int* adr, ...){
    char a[1];
    printf("cnt: %p, adr: %p\n", &cnt, &adr);
}

int main(void){
    _func(0, (int*)1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
    return 0;
}
```

... that is compiled with

`gcc -m32 -O0 main.c`

and it outputs this:

```
cnt: 0xff911960, adr: 0xff91193c
```

which is 36 (0x24) bytes difference. And the question is **why** it is? Isn't is should be `sizeof(cnt)`?

But if I  remove `char a[1]` or add `-O2` flag, the difference would be 4 bytes (as usual).

What causes this behavior?

PS: on compiler explorer website, the offset is 4 bytes all the time.

Comment: Please show a [mcve] including `#include`s. Also change `&cnt, &adr` to `(void*)&cnt, (void*)&adr`. Then try again. Also tell us what platform your code is running on

Comment: *should be sizeof(cnt)?* Where do you get that from? For variadic functions it is likely to pass the variable arguments and the last fixed argument on the stack. For all other arguments they could be passed in registers. If you then decide to take its address and force the compiler to store it in the called function, there is no need to use consecutive addresses.

Comment: @Gerhardh with `-m32` the arguments are not passed by registers AFAIK, but the truth is, we don't know what compiler and platform the OP has.

Comment: If you really want to know what is going in, you need to check the assembler created by the compiler

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`&cnt` and `&adr` are addresses of parameters. Parameters are variables local to the function that are initialized to the argument values passed by the caller. The compiler is not required to use the same space for parameters that is used to pass the arguments.

When an argument is passed on the stack, a compiler might or might not reuse its stack space for the parameter. When an argument is passed in a processor register and an address is needed for it, as because a program takes the address and prints it, then the compiler has to reserve space for the parameter on the stack, copy the value from the register to the stack space (as with a store instruction), and use the address of the stack space.

When the compiler is laying out stack space for this, it does not need to care that `cnt` and `adr` are consecutive parameters. It can organize data about all the stack space it needs—for parameters, for local variables, for the return address, for its own purposes, whatever—and then just assign stack space for those things in any order. So you should not expect there to be any close relationship between the addresses of `cnt` and `adr`.

(For functions with variable arguments, the compiler needs someway to implement the variable argument list features. This usually involves having the variable arguments consecutive in memory after the last fixed argument, which would be `adr` in the example. This does not impose any relationship between `cnt` and `adr`.)

Comment: I've tested, and they are consecutive ONLY IF char a[1] is not present... on my machine ofc


P.S Im implementing own va_* macro to understand how they works.

Comment: they also consecutive if adr is not a pointer.